# Mastercard MoneySend API and Visa Direct API

Tags: mastercard, visa-api

I want to create an app like Google Wallet for my country, Romania. I emailed Visa developer and I received the next email.

> "Hello,
>   Thanks for your interest in visa direct API. There is an
>   acquirer in Romania who supports visa direct transaction BANCA
>   TRANSILVANIA S.A.
>
> > However, There are many elements and requirements
> >     to offering a comprehensive Visa Direct program of which the APIs are
> >     just one component. First and foremost you must be sponsored by a Visa
> >     acquiring financial institution or work through a payment aggregator
> >     or facilitator to offer a Visa Direct program. You must identify and
> >     work with a sponsoring Visa acquiring financial institution or payment
> >     aggregator or facilitator who will help guide you through the process
> >     of onboarding a Visa Direct program. If you already have an acquiring
> >     sponsor, please let us know. For more information on Visa Direct
> >     programs, refer to www.visa.com/visadirect   Thanks Sanobar Visa
> >     Developer Platform "

1. What do you understand from this email?
2. So this means I can't use the APIs from https://developer.visa.com?
3. If I can't use their API from the developer website, this means I must use a payment aggregator? I don't know any payment agregator that can use my local currency (RON  - Romania). Can you sugest some payment aggregators please...
4. These APIs (Mastercard MoneySend and Visa Direct) are good for what I need?

Answer (score 1):

you need a partner with a financial institution like a bank or